# About git commit error: pathspec 'A' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, commit

```
C:\Users\me\React_projects\react-basic\habit-tracker>git commit "habittracker"
error: pathspec 'habittracker' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

My operating system is Windows.
Let me know what I can do to commit!!!!

Comment: did you try `git fetch` or `git checkout` ?

Comment: Do you actually have a file named `habittracker` at the root of your repo? (same level as the `.git`)

Comment: when i input `git chekout`, fatal: `You are on a branch yet to be born` is printed out. How can I move on to the next step?

Comment: That last comment (that `git checkout` produces the error message `You are on a branch yet to be born`) should be part of the question. It tells me what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

there is a very comprehensive guide to git from Atlassian:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control

for the time being, though -
go to your working directory and write these commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'your message describing what was done'
```